# Drupal Commerce Discounts does not show the discount for users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I am working at a drupal page and I have to add the discount option to the shop. But it does not work. At the end I added 3 images where you can the error - but first I will describe the problem.

I added a discount (Buy more then 1 Item and you will get x percent of discount).The Problem now is that this discount is never shown for the user in the cart and/or checkout - the big problem with this is that now its impossible to pay with paypal (because there is a problem with the amount values - the drupal system tells paypal the right price (with the discount) but this is not the same like the price the user is shown).

My question is now: 
- Where can it be that there is an error (This wasnt a clean drupal page - I just started to work at a existing drupal page - maybe there is somewhere smth that the discount is not showing ?)

My modules and versions:

1. Commerce Discount **7.x-1.0-alpha4**
2. Commerce Discount Date **7.x-1.0-alpha4**
3. Commerce Discount Extra **7.x-1.0-alpha3**
4. Commerce Discount Usage **7.x-1.0-alpha4**

Here are the screenshots of the **cart**, **checkout** and **admin commerce order view**:

User - Cart (Without the discount)
[image: User - Cart (Without the discount)]

User - Checkout (Without the discount)
[image: User - Checkout (Without the discount)]

Logged in Admin - Order View in "Commerce -> Orders" (With discount)
[image: Logged in Admin - Order View in "Commerce -> Orders" (With discount)]

Product Type "Product" Display settings
[image: Product Type "Product" Display settings]

Answer (score 0):

If the price is getting sent to paypal with the discount, then i think you might need to set the display in `Product display` page. `?q=admin/commerce/products/types/[PRODUCT]/display`.

Next to `Price` field; set the `Format` column to show the savings, then press the gear icon for more controlling options.

Comment: I edited my question and added the picture of the product type settings. As you see the settings eems to be normal and right ?